# history expansion without execution?

Tags: bash, command-history, history-expansion

!924 will execute that line from history.
Is there a syntax where I can simply pull that line from history to the current line so I can edit it: i.e.: like using the up arrow with a built in search feature?

Comment: @VojtechTrefny I did find that answer and while that works, I thought there was a way to bring that command from history with my cursor at the end of the line. basically !109:p is adding that line to the top of the history so you can then use the up arrow... I think :)

Comment: Not sure if that is possible with history. You can use Ctrl+R to search the command history and use End to move the cursor to the end of line. But that's a little but different.